# An invertible hermitian element of a C*-algebra has a logarithm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Suppose $ A$ is a C*-algebra. Show that an invertible hermitian element of $A$ has a logarithm. ($a$ has a logarithm if there is an element $b\in A$ such that $e^b=a$)

If $a\in A_+$ then it's easy for me to show it, but if $a$ is self-adjoint, then $\log$ function is not continuous on $\sigma(a)$. How can come up by this? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if $a$ is Hermitian and invertible, then $\sigma(a)$ is contained in the real line and stays away from 0.  So you can choose a branch of the $\log$ function that is continuous on $\sigma(a)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: but the negative part of real line does not belong to domain of $\log$ function. It's my problem. I can not define $\log$ on this part.

Comment: I am speaking of the [complex $\log$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).  You can define it continuously on the complex plane minus a ray from the origin, which you can choose.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks for your attention.